# How to open new activity after clicking on childitem in expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am working on expandablelistview to open heading then subheading. However, when I clicked on subheading it should open new activity.

Please help me here, instead of toast that says childitem is clicked.

```
private OnChildClickListener myListItemClicked =  new OnChildClickListener() {

    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        //get the group header
        HeaderInfo headerInfo = SectionList.get(groupPosition);
        //get the child info
        DetailInfo detailInfo =  headerInfo.getProductList().get(childPosition);
        //display it or do something with it
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked on Detail " + headerInfo.getName()
                + "/" + detailInfo.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ThisActivity with your current activity and YourNewActivity to your new activity you want to go

```
private OnChildClickListener myListItemClicked = new OnChildClickListener() {

    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        //get the group header
        HeaderInfo headerInfo = SectionList.get(groupPosition);
        //get the child info
        DetailInfo detailInfo =  headerInfo.getProductList().get(childPosition);
        //display it or do something with it
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked on Detail " + headerInfo.getName()
                + "/" + detailInfo.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    switch(childPosition) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, YourNewActivity0.class);
        break;
    case 1:
        Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, YourNewActivity1.class);
        break;
    case 2:
        Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, YourNewActivity2.class);
        break;
}

    startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Suppose, I have three childitems, in a heading, then perhaps it will open a single activity all the time. I want to open three separate activity when clicked on childitems child1, child2, child.

Comment: This is a fast and cheating way if you have small amount of actions.

Comment: Oh..Yes. I want to act this childitem as button to open any activity. Can you please tell me any link to do this. Well, thanks for your response.

Comment: If you have small amount of code and each go to a COMPLETELY DIFFERENT activities, then this is the fastest way to do, if all child goes to a single activity but having different info on that activity then it will be another implementation. (I have updated the code with a switch case)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Angus Tay; 
I got Idea from your reply.
I found my answer as given below and it worked for me...

```
switch(groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent c1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity0.class);
                            startActivity(c1);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent d2= new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity1.class);
                            startActivity(d2);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Intent d3= new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity2.class);
                            startActivity(d3);
                            break;


                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent d1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity0.class);
                            startActivity(d1);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent d2= new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity1.class);
                            startActivity(d2);
                            break;


                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent a1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity0.class);
                            startActivity(a1);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent a2= new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourNewActivity1.class);
                            startActivity(a2);
                            break;

                    }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```